# Allow creation of folder on apache2 in Ubuntu Server

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, file-io

I'm creating a site which I'm going to host on an Ubuntu Server. I have a user registration form on my site, which creates a user and a folder for that user (if filled out correctly). The form in handled by PHP and I'm running Apache 2 on the server. When I run the code on my laptop the folder is created, but when I run the same code on the server the folder is not there. I guess that it has something to do with permisssion. How can I tell apache that the code should have write permission in a specific folder called "users" located in /var/www/mysite/public/users/ ???

Comment: Run "chmod 777 /var/www/mysite/public/users/" in the shell?

Comment: apache user and group on ubuntu server are `www-data`, in `public` directory run commands: `chmod -R ugo-rwx,ugo+rwX *` and `chown -R [your_user].www-data *`, `777` isn't recommended.

Comment: What exactly does the code above? If I'm not supposed to give all permissions, then how should I make PHP create the folder and the files inside of it?

Comment: whatabout chmod 1777 and then chown -R [your_user].www-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using chmod command that provides folder permission. Something like

```
chmod 777 -R foldername
```

Comment: I have vhanged the mode and ownership of the file. When I do a ls - l I get the following: "drwxrwx--T [myName] www-data". Is that want I want?

Comment: Yes Try now what are u getting?

Comment: Yes it is safe if u have any security concern change the permission to 775

Answer (score 0):

If security is not an issue I would suggest:

```
chmod 775 -R /var/www/
chown -R [your_user]:www-data /var/www/
```

So both apache2 (www-data) and you can edit folders and files inside /var/www (or /var/www/html if this is your folder).

Notice that this may have issues with git and other tools that capture folder permissions (eg with git you may commit files with 775).